# Fahrenheit to Celsius temperature conversion doesn't print the expected result

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    double f;

    printf ("What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &f);

    double x = (f-32)*(5/9);
    printf ("%d degrees Fahrenheit \n",f); 
    printf ("%d degrees Celsius",x); 
    system("PAUSE");  

    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to be printing the address of variable `f` instead of the value; it's probably a syntax mistake.

Comment: See *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f* for info on using **scanf()** and **printf()** with doubles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `printf()` calls, `%d` should be `%f` (or perhaps `%.2f`):

```
printf ("%f degrees Farenheit \n",f); 
printf ("%f degrees Celsius",x);
```

You also need to change:

```
double x = (f-32)*(5/9);
```

to

```
double x = (f-32)*(5.0/9);
```

In C, integer division (a division where both dividend and divisor are integer types) truncates, so 5/9 is always 0.

Also, the conversion specification for `double` with `scanf()` is `%lf`:

```
if (scanf("%lf", &f) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a valid floating point number\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Use "%f" for both float and double; a float argument to a variadic
function like printf is automatically promoted to double.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` means "decimal integer". You are using `double`s, not `int`s. So use `%lf` in the `scanf()` and `%f` in the `printf()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    float c;
    float f;

    printf ("What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?\n");
    scanf ("%f", &f);

    c = (f-32)*(5.0/9.0);
    printf ("%f degrees Fahrenheit \n",f);
    printf ("%f degrees Celsius \n",c);
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is `double x = (f-32)*(5/9)`.  `5/9` is zero, since you're using integer division, so `x` will have the value `0.0` for all inputs.  For floating-point division, use floating-point numbers (like `5.0/9.0`).

Second, `%d` is for printing integers.  Use `%f` to print floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

adding to what others have said, `%d` stands for "decimal" (as opposed to `%x` being "hexadecimal")

for floating point numbers, or in your case double precision floating point numbers, use `%f`

Answer (score 0):

9 times out of 10, when you use `printf` to display debug data and find it displaying bizzare results, you have a bug in your `printf` call.

This is why I now try to avoid `printf`. The dynamic format bit is neat, but the extreme type-unsafety of the call makes it too often a source of bugs rather than enlightenement.

Comment: Get yourself a compiler that tells you when you make mistakes - and learn the rules so you don't make mistakes.