# Converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius and viceversa in C

Tags: c, data-conversion, temperature

I'm working on a program to convert F to C and vice-versa. The thing is, I've seen similar programs where you first enter if the conversion is from degree `F` to degree `C` or vice-versa, and then you Enter the data. I just want kind of a more user friendly version, where you Enter the data as "35F" and it gives you output.

So far I have basically %70 of the program done but I think I'm having problems when reading the Temperature and the character together in the same `scanf()`. I was wondering if it is possible to do that in just 1 line and if I'm aiming in the right directions.

Currently the program is running fine but the Output is always `0.000000` ):
I would love your help and thank your in advance!

```
float temperature, Farenheit, Celsius;
char unit0;
char unit1 = 'C';
char unit2 = 'F';

printf("Enter the temperature (Ex. 35F): ");
scanf("%f%c", &temperature, &unit0);

if (unit0 == unit2)
{
    Celsius = (temperature-32) * (5/9) ;
    printf("The temperature %f%c is equal to %f in Celsius", temperature, unit0, Celsius);
}
else
if (unit0 == unit1)
{
    Farenheit = (9/5)*temperature+32;
    printf("The temperature %f%c is equal to %f in Fahrenheit", temperature, unit0, Fahrenheit);
}
```

Comment: Integer division will get you every time...

Comment: Also use %.1f to get the output to 1decimal place or else you could end up with less than pretty output.

Comment: duplicates: [Fahrenheit to Celsius temperature conversion doesn't print the expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193290/995714), [5/9 is not taking by the C compiler to Calculate fc (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47482650/995714), [Division result is always zero (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2345902/995714)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `(5/9)` to `5.0/9.0`. If you use integer division, this gives you 0 after rounding.

You should do the same for 9/5

Comment: i work 9.0 to 5. everday