# sscanf for doubles

Tags: c, scanf

This is a simple problem, but I can't see it:

```
  char *s = "f 8.649292" ;
  double d ;
  sscanf( s, "f %f", &d ) ;

  printf( "d is %f\n", d ) ;
```

Why is `d` not containing the double value `8.649292`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oh wait, nevermind.  d needs to be a `float`.

And to make it work you could use `%lf` for a double

```
  char *s = "f 8.649292 " ;
  double d ;
  sscanf( s, "f %lf", &d ) ;

  printf( "d is %lf\n", d ) ;
```

Comment: `%lf` is needed for scanning a double with `scanf`, but it's incorrect to use `%lf` with `printf`. Simply use `%f`.

Comment: @R.. [Explanation of your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)