# C complex number and printf

Tags: c, printf, complex-numbers

How to print ( with printf ) complex number? For example, if I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
int main(void)
{
    double complex dc1 = 3 + 2*I;
    double complex dc2 = 4 + 5*I;
    double complex result;

    result = dc1 + dc2;
    printf(" ??? \n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

..what conversion specifiers ( or something else ) should I use instead "???"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
printf("%f + i%f\n", creal(result), cimag(result));
```

I don't believe there's a specific format specifier for the C99 complex type.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but as creal() and cimag() both return doubles, shouldn't the format specifier be '%lf' instead of simply '%f'?

Comment: Additional improvement - macro which reacts to sign of imaginary part:
`#define printfc(c) printf("%f%c%fi",creal(c),(cimag(c)>=0.0f)? '+':'\0',cimag(c))`

Comment: @JonDoe It doesn't matter. printf is not scanf, f and lf are both ok for double. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Are you aware that `%c` will also output `\0`? Better use `%s` with `? "+" : ""`

Answer (score 20):

Let `%+f` choose the correct sign for you for imaginary part:

```
printf("%f%+fi\n", crealf(I), cimagf(I));
```

Output:

```
0.000000+1.000000i
```

Note that `i` is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because the complex number is stored as two real numbers back-to-back in memory, doing

```
printf("%g + i%g\n", result);
```

will work as well, but generates compiler warnings with gcc because the type and number of parameters doesn't match the format.  I do this in a pinch when debugging but don't do it in production code.

Comment: I would argue that relying on undefined behavior when debugging is a bad idea. Undefined behavior can often cause other subtle bugs, exacerbating the problem. Plus it is all too common for throwaway debugging code to end up in production.

Comment: This will only work if the platform's calling conventions specifies that complex numbers are passed in the same way as two real numbers, which is in no way guaranteed.

Comment: It is, however, for debugging only, quite a nice hack.  Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Currently using a compiler with _Complex but nothing else. Using the back-to-back in mem in a safer way as such: `printf("%f%+fi\n", (double)D, *((double*)&D+1));`

Answer (score -3):

Using GNU C, this works:

```
printf("%f %f\n", complexnum);
```

Or, if you want a suffix of "i" printed after the imaginary part:

```
printf("%f %fi\n", complexnum);
```

Comment: I don't think that's true: https://wandbox.org/permlink/h7O5hbDp0FzxKtXc Look at the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13519304/4944425) to see why it might work.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined