# OUTPUT in C printf

Tags: c, gcc

What's the meaning of `-6i` in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1234;
    printf("%d",-6i);
}
```

Comment: I can tell you how to find out.

Comment: @mohan.gade: paste your code yourself: http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: "what means -6i" in a C program - now *that's* a good question.

Comment: @mohan.gade: Sorry, I thought it was very obvious. You can find the output of your code by running it.

Comment: yaa I have run it. It print 1234 following two spaces after 4.I does not got the meaning . Heance I asked question.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your real question, `-6i` is a complex constant (a GCC extension).  From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html:

> To write a constant with a complex data type, use the suffix 'i' or 'j' (either one; they are equivalent). For example, `2.5fi` has type `_Complex float` and `3i` has type `_Complex int`. Such a constant always has a pure imaginary value, but you can form any complex value you like by adding one to a real constant. This is a GNU extension; if you have an ISO C99 conforming C library (such as GNU libc), and want to construct complex constants of floating type, you should include `<complex.h>` and use the macros `I` or `_Complex_I` instead.

So the `i` in `-6i` has nothing to do with the variable `i`, just like the `f` in the float constant `-1.0f` would have nothing to do with a variable named `f`.

A a side note, `printf("%d",-6i);` is undefined behavior, since the format spec `%d` doesn't deal with complex arguments.  GCC doesn't make any promises (as far as I know) about the representation of a complex type.  You can't say much of anything about what that `printf()` would do.

I think that to print the complex value, you'd have to extract each component of the complex value separately (I don't think glibc's `printf()` has a format spec extension that deals with GCC's complex types).  Something like:

```
printf("%d %d\n",__real__ -6i, __imag__ -6i);
printf("%f %f\n",__real__ -6.i, __imag__ -6.i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you change you code a little bit:

```
int main(){
   int i = 1234;
   printf("%d",-6*i); 
   }
```

You may get `-7404` back.

And to answer the second question, please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099433/c-complex-number-and-printf).

Comment: @MichaelBurr - Tengis's program is different from the OPs. Tengis program will give you `-7404`. That said, Kudos for being the only person to understand OP's question.