# FFT of an array of complex numbers

Tags: c, complex-numbers, fftw

Using FFTW, I want to perform the IFFT of an array of complex numbers, reading data from file "numbers.txt" (where they are stored in the format  a+b*I, one complex number per each row). I have tried with the following, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main(void)
{
fftw_complex *in;
fftw_complex *out;
float re,im;
int size;

printf("Insert size");
scanf("%d", &size);

FILE *file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

int i=0;

while(fscanf(file, "%f+%fi", &re, &im) > 0) {
in[i]=re+im*I;
i++;
}
fclose(file);

 fftw_complex *out_cpx;

 fftw_plan ifft;
 out_cpx = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*size);
 out = (double *) malloc(size*sizeof(double));

 ifft = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(size, out_cpx, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);   //Setup fftw plan 

 fftw_execute(ifft);

 printf("Input:    \tOutput:\n");
 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
 printf("%f\t%f\n",(in[i]),out[i]);
 }

 fftw_destroy_plan(ifft);
 fftw_free(out_cpx);
 free(out);


 return 0;
 }
```

Sample input is (one number per each row):

```
0+0*I
0.01198+-0.0825632*I
1.32139e-05+1.94777e-05*I 
-1.18289e-11+7.30045e-12*I 
2.71773e-20+0*I 
-1.18289e-11+-7.30045e-12*I 
1.32139e-05+-1.94777e-05*I 
0.01198+0.0825632*I
```

In particular, I have problems in reading the data from the file. Does someone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Edit:

After some improvements, I'm now using this modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>


 int main(void)
{
fftw_complex *in;
fftw_complex *out;
double re,im;
int size;
int i=0;
FILE *file;
fftw_plan ifft;

printf("Insert size");
if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 1)
    return 1;

in = fftw_malloc(sizeof(*in)*size);
out = fftw_malloc(sizeof(*out)*size);

file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

for (i = 0; i < size && fscanf(file, "%lf+%lf*I\n", &re, &im) == 2; i++)
{
    in[i]= re+im*I;
}

fclose(file);
// Error if i != size?


ifft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, in, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(ifft);

printf("Input:    \tOutput:\n");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
printf("%lf+%lfI\t%lf+%lfI\n", creal(in[i]), cimag(in[i]), creal(out[i]), cimag(out[i]));
}

fftw_destroy_plan(ifft);
fftw_free(in);
fftw_free(out);
//free(out);

return 0;
}
```

The problem now is that I always get a real-valued transformed array. How can I fix it?

Comment: "it doesn't work" lacks detail.  Please post sample input and described what occurred.

Comment: There's a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740255/fftw-producing-real-instead-of-complex-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have several problems.  The calling sequence for [`fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#index-fftw_005fplan_005fdft_005fc2r_005f1d-195) is as follows:

> The inverse transforms, taking complex input (storing the non-redundant half of a logically Hermitian array) to real output, are given by:
>
> ```
>  fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(int n0,
>                                 fftw_complex *in, double *out,
>                                 unsigned flags);
> ```

Thus, you have the following problems:

1. You never allocate the `fftw_complex *in` array.  It should be

   ```
   in = fftw_malloc(sizeof(*in)*size);
   // And later
   fftw_free(in);
   ```
2. There is no need for `in_cpx`, since `in` is complex.
3. Suggest also using `fftw_malloc` for `out`.
4. `fftw_complex` is double precision so `re` and `im` should be as well.
5. Your `printf` [will not work for C99 complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099433/c-complex-number-and-printf)
6. Check the returns from scanf and fscanf.
7. **Update** as chux says above, break out of the loop when i >= size.  Also, check to make sure that i == size when the loop is complete.

I don't have c99 available, so I don't have access to the new [built-in `complex` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c), but a fix might look like (not tested):

```
int main(void)
{
    fftw_complex *in;
    double *out;
    double re,im;
    int size;
    int i=0;
    FILE *file;
    fftw_plan ifft;

    printf("Insert size");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 1)
        return 1;

    in = fftw_malloc(sizeof(*in)*size);
    out = fftw_malloc(sizeof(*out)*size);

    file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < size && fscanf(file, "%lf+%lf*I\n", &re, &im) == 2; i++)
    {
        in[i]= re + im*I;
    }

    fclose(file);
    // Error if i != size?

    ifft = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(size, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);   //Setup fftw plan 

    fftw_execute(ifft);

    printf("Input:    \tOutput:\n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf+i%lf\t%lf\n", creal(in[i]), cimag(in[i]), out[i]);
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(ifft);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After making the program run, it produces the following output:*** Error in `./program': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000144e120 ***
 (core dump created)

Comment: Sample input is (one number per each row):  0+0*I
0.01198+-0.0825632*I
1.32139e-05+1.94777e-05*I
-1.18289e-11+7.30045e-12*I
2.71773e-20+0*I
-1.18289e-11+-7.30045e-12*I
1.32139e-05+-1.94777e-05*I
0.01198+0.0825632*I

Comment: @johnhenry - 1) your "fscanf()" won't parse the file format you have shown.  I tried to fix the "fscanf" call.  2) There was a leftover "free" which I forgot to remove.

Comment: Many thanks! Should I fix the same way the printf() in the loop?

Comment: since I would like my transformed vector to be complex as well

Comment: @johnhenry - I don't understand your last two comments.  1) Are you seeing a bug with your output results?  2) `fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d` produces real output.  If you want complex inputs and outputs, you need a different function I reckon, maybe one here: http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-DFTs.html#Complex-DFTs

Comment: you're right, let's use fftw_plan_dft_1d, since my output must be complex

Comment: I have edited my question, now I use fftw_plan_dft_1d , but I get real values!

Answer (score 1):

this

```
printf("%f\t%f\n",(in[i]),out[i]);
```

has to be

```
printf("%f + %f j\t%f + %f j\n", in[i][0], in[i][1], out[i][0], out[i][1]);
```

since `fftw_complex` is just

```
typedef double fftw_complex[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Code has no memory allocated for input  (this is the major issue)

   ```
   fftw_complex *in;
   ...
   in = malloc(size * sizeof *in); 
   // or
   in = calloc(size, sizeof *in);
   ...
   in[i]=re+im*I;
   ...
   free(in);
   ```
2. While loop should check for `== 2` not `> 0`.   Also added spaces to allow spacing in complex number.  Suggest OP provide sample input if this does not work.

   ```
   // while(fscanf(file, "%f+%fi", &re, &im) > 0) {
   while(fscanf(file, "%f +%f i", &re, &im) == 2) {
   ```
3. Code does not check that after loop `i == size`.
4. Suggest easier to code and maintain `malloc()` style:

   ```
   // out_cpx = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*size);
   out_cpx = fftw_malloc(size * sizeof *out_cpx);

   // out = (double *) malloc(size*sizeof(double));
   out = malloc(size * sizeof *out);
   ```
5. Alternate format may be more informative

   ```
   // printf("%f\t%f\n",(in[i]),out[i]);
   printf("%e\t%e\n",(in[i]),out[i]);
   ```
6. Robust code would check the return value from `scanf("%d", &size);` and `malloc()`.
7. Re-formatting code would make it easier to understand.