# How to insert character in-between value using printf?

Tags: c

I have a problem. I need to insert a specific char (number sign) into my output value. I am not allowed to use if statement and "? :" statement. My output needs to look like this:

```
9999.999(+/-)i9999.999
```

Where character "i" needs to go right after the 2nd number sign. Here is my code so far:

```
void show(struct z z) {
    printf("%.3fi%.3f", z.re, z.im);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: you are missing the + character

Comment: i love the 'i am not allowed to use the if statement'. Another assignment with 'clever' rules

Comment: Number sign is `#`.

Comment: 2nd value can be either +/-, the thing is that I need to put "i" right after the sign.

Comment: to clarify Eugene comment. What you have should work (apart from +). So what is your problem? Does it not compile? run? give the wrong result?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a ternary expression.

Comment: perhaps this question and the answers would help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4099433/1212725

Comment: so your actual question is "how can I put a + or - depending on the value of z.im?"

Comment: Isn't it more usual to place the *`i`* on the right with an imaginary number, like `9999.999 + 9999.999i`?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes but then this would be too easy, just add 'i' after the number. Here we need the sign character then 'i' then the abs value of z.im

Comment: I think you're saying that the `+` or `-` corresponds to the sign of `z.im`, but you didn't actually say so. Can you update your question to clarify that point?

Comment: You mention in a comment that you're not allowed to use the `?:` operator. Please update your question to say that as well.

Comment: @pm100 still need to force a sign for the imaginary part, like format `"%+f"`.

Comment: can't you just do this? `printf("%f%+fi\n", z.re, z.im);`, and let the format specifier choose the correct sign for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without if or ternary

```
void show(struct z z) {
    printf("%.3f%ci%.3f", z.re, "+-"[z.im<0], fabs(z.im));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I somehow doubt the instructor have meant this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well if is banned, ternary is banned, this is a 'clever ' trick so maybe it is OK. Who knows

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional (aka "ternary") expression to print `+` or `-` depending on the sign of the imaginary part. Then print the absolute value of the imaginary part.

```
void show(struct z z) {
    printf("%.3f%ci%.3f", z.re, (z.im >= 0 ? '+' : '-'), fabs(z.im));
}
```

If you can't use a ternary, either, you can format the number with a forced sign into a string, then swap the `i` and sign in the result.

```
void show(struct z z) {
    char result[100];
    sprintf(result, "%.3fi%+.3f", z.re, z.im);
    int iloc = strchr(result, 'i');
    result[iloc] = result[iloc+1];
    result[iloc+1] = 'i';
    printf("%s", result);
}
```

Comment: yup, the 'if' rule was clearly intended to force use of ternary. Now I wonder if its doable without ternary or if - intersting challenge

Comment: The thing is, that's not allowed either... I just didn't know how it was called.

Comment: ternary not allowed either?

Comment: @pm100 No problem: printf("...", z.re, '-'-(z.im >= 0)*2, fabs(z.im));

Comment: @RPAnimation Is this exercise associated with a lesson on a particular topic? What is the topic?

Comment: @Ctx I would bet the instructor would forbid it as well if could think about it :)

Comment: if you use the `%+f` format specifier, it will choose the correct sign for you

Comment: @bruceg Yes, but it puts it after the `i`, not before.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the OP is confused about where the `i` is supposed to go.

Comment: @bruceg Possibly. Complex numbers are normally `<realpart>(+-)<imaginarypart>i`

Answer (score 1):

To properly handle `-0.0` and `NAN`, extract the sign with `signbit()` and use the string trick as in [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729509/2410359).

> The `signbit` macro determines whether the sign of its argument value is negative. (footnote)
>   The `signbit` macro returns a nonzero value if and only if the sign of its argument value
>   is negative.
>   The `signbit` macro reports the sign of all values, including infinities, zeros, and NaNs.

```
#include <math.h>

// 9999.999(+/-)i9999.999
printf("%.3f%ci%.3f", z.re, "-+"[!signbit(z.im)], fabs(z.im));
```