# Parsing user input using time_t

Tags: c, time-t

My idea is, if user enters `t = 2.5`, then I extract 2 and 0.5 separately in 2 different variables. But I am unable to do that.

Here is the code:

```
$ export LT_LEAK_START=1.5
$ echo $LT_LEAK_START
   1.5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
 double d;
 time_t t;
 long nsec;

 d=strtod(getenv("LT_LEAK_START"), NULL);
 t=(time_t)d;

 nsec=d-(double)((time_t)d); // Extract fractional part as time_t always whole no.
 printf("d = %lf\n",d);
 printf("t = %u, nsec = %f\n",d,nsec);
}
```

Output is:

```
# ./a.out 
  d = 1.500000
  t = 0, nsec = 0.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is broken. You're actually writing the value of `d` twice in the following code:

```
nsec=d-(double)((time_t)d); // Extract fractional part as time_t always whole no.
printf("d = %lf\n",d);
printf("t = %u, nsec = %f\n",d,nsec);
```

If you'd written this:

```
nsec=d-(double)((time_t)d); // Extract fractional part as time_t always whole no.
printf("d = %lf\n",d);
printf("t = %u, nsec = %f\n",t,nsec);
```

Then you'd have the output:

```
d = 1.500000
t = 1, nsec = 0.000000
```

It's now clearer that you have a rounding error. In this case, you cast away all the decimal places by assigning 0.5 to `nsec`, a `long`. Make `nsec` a `float` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign `.5` to a `long` which isn't going to happen.

```
double d = 1.5;
int i = (int)d;
double j = d - (double)i;

printf("%d %f\n",i,j);
```

Comment: What is the solution in that case. I am not exactly getting how to proceed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are also trying to store a fractional value in a long.  You either need to multiply this by 1000 or make `nsec` a double.

`nsec=d-(double)((time_t)d);`

If d is 1.5, the result of the right hand side would be 0.5, which will implicitly cast down to 0 when it gets stored in nsec.

Comment: He's using the format flag `%f`, so `nsec` should be a `float`, not a `double`.

Comment: %f is a printf formatting flag and isn't related to what you are describing.  %f is suitable for displaying both floats and doubles.  The f in %f simply means 'floating point' it doesn't mean single precision floating point.  %f will display a double just fine.

Comment: @Luke: Really? Then what's `%lf`? (It _is_ related, because if he's using the wrong type then he's invoking UB.)

Comment: Yes really, the `l` modifier doesn't apply to floating point, see 'length' in the link below.  If you mean `%Lf`, then that is a long double, which is more precise than a double. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @Luke: Nah, I meant `%lf`. If `%f` is safe with `double`, then OK. However I'd prefer a C reference to a C++ reference. C++ is a different language. (And there *are* compatibility differences in C++'s C standard library.)

Comment: http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output suggests that the `l` modifier most certainly does apply.

Comment: The `l` is used and valid for `scanf`, but it makes no difference for `printf` due to argument promotion.  When `%f` is used, floats and doubles alike are promoted to doubles, thus there is no difference and `%lf` will be treated exactly like `%l` when used in `printf`.  Because of its use in `scanf`, people are often confused and think that it should be used with `printf` as well.  Just a note, `printf` is part of the standard library and is not part of either the C nor the C++ programming language.  You are correct, your syntax is valid.  But it is not needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f backs up my claim above.

Comment: @Luke: OK, that's cool then. :) (BTW, in C++, the library *is* part of the language. Not sure whether the same could be said for C, but I was clearly referring to the language+library body as a whole anyway.)