# Why does `"%c"` exist in `printf` if `char` is converted to `int`?

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

In C you have the `"%c"` and `"%f"` formats flags for `printf`- and `scanf`-like functions. Both of these function use variable length arguments `...`, which always convert `floats` to `doubles` and `chars` to `ints`.

My question is, if this conversion occurs, why do separate flags for `char` and `float` exist? Why not just use the same flags as for `int` and `double`?

> **Related question:**
>   [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210590/627005)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the way it gets printed out is different.

```
printf("%d \n",100); //prints 100
printf("%c \n",100); //prints d - the ascii character represented by 100
```

Comment: Oh.. obviously. What about `float`, though?

Comment: @PaulManta: The `%f` formatting flag expects a `double` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Because `float` and `double`  have different machine representations or sizes, and calling conventions: many processors have registers dedicated to floating point which might be used for argument passing.

And the C standard requires that `short` arguments are converted to `int` and `float` arguments are converted to `double`.

Comment: Note that these conversions aren't done for all arguments, only for arguments where the function declaration doesn't specify the parameter type.

Comment: @Keith: what's relevant to this question is that the promotions are always applied to varargs. Which as you say is a subset of "arguments where the function declaration doesn't specify the parameter type".