# Double returns 0 in recursion, but works fine when int

Tags: c, recursion, double

I don't get why it works fine if you change all the `double` into `int`,

**is there something wrong with my printf statements?**

**you use `%f` or `%lf` for `double`, right?**

```
/*
double power(double a, int b) that calculates the power ab. You are allowed to use the
multiplication operator *.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
double power(double a,int b)
{
    double buffer;
    if(b > 1)
    {
        buffer = a * power(a,b-1);
        return buffer;
    }
    else
        return a;
}
int main(void)
{
    double a;
    int b;
    int buffer;
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    buffer = power(a,b);
    printf("%f",buffer);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Try `%lf` for `double`, `double` for `buffer`.

Comment: The [answer by cnicutar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12235250/335858answer) correctly identified two issues in your code that will make your code work, but there is a third issue that may show up when your end-users enter a very large `b`: your program may overflow stack, or take too long to produce the result, depending on the optimizer settings. You need to read about [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to address that problem.

Comment: If possible, you should adjust your compiler preferences (or *preference*) so that you will be warned about mismatches between types and format specifiers when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int buffer;
> printf("%f",buffer);
> ```

You're using the wrong specifier in printf, which is a serious problem because `printf` cannot convert arguments. Either use `%d` or change `buffer` into a double.

---

As a second problem, you'll also want to use `%lf` instead of `%f` in `scanf`, since `a` is a `double`, not a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%f",&a);
```

You need to read your double by `%lf`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210590/912144) for why you need `%lf` with `scanf` but not with `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that on your system, `int` appears to be of the same length as  `float` but not as `double` - when you scanf() a double, you loose half of it (and by the way, feeding a wrong format specifier to scanf is undefined behaviour). You have to use `%lf` for doubles.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `%lf` for double in scanf See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f) question.
In place of:

```
scanf("%f",&a);
```

use this:

```
scanf("%lf",&a);
```

Also in the main function the type of buffer should be `double` not `int`.