# What's the difference between LONG float and double in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

So I know that there's a large difference in the precision of floats and doubles. I get that. Promise.

But, in C++, when calling scanf and printf, the notation used to specify a double is "%lf", and that stands for long float, right? So while a float is less precise than a double, a LONG float (presumedly called long float because it can be "longer" by having more terms) is the same accuracy and therefore essentially the same thing?

Just to clarify, here's what I mean:

```
double number = 3.14159;
printf("The number is %lf", number);
```

So the root of my question: Is long float another name for double?

Comment: There is no `long float` and compiler should give you an error. Conceptually though, you can call it `long float`, and that won't be incorrect.

Comment: I'm not defining it as a long float.  sorry for the confusion.  I made an edit to the post to clarify.

Comment: @milleniumbug, but there might be a long double: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such a type as `long float` within my knowledge.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf) gives you information about why people use `lf` to print `double` with `printf` if this is the cause of your confusion.

By courtesy of @Jerry Coffin:

> "%f" is the (or at least "a") correct format for a double. There is no format for a float, because **if you attempt to pass a float to printf, it'll be promoted to double before printf receives it.** "%lf" is also acceptable under the current standard -- **the l is specified as having no effect if followed by the f conversion specifier** (among others).

So the reason is that when people do:

```
 printf("The number is %lf", number);
```

It is equivalent to do:

```
printf("The number is %f", number); //l has no effect when printing double
```

Comment: I use a `%lf` when scanning for a double and it works.  And according to @milleniumbug below, `%f` does not.  So by that reasoning, isn't `%lf` the "right" format for doubles?

Comment: @Nealon I think this post should clear your confusion if there is any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f

Answer (score 5):

`printf` specifier names don't have anything in common with names of types.

They are just named that way so they are short and easy to remember.

float -> double -> long double

%f -> %lf -> %Lf

(also, they couldn't name `printf` double specifier as `%d` because that name is already reserved for decimal representation of `int` (compared to octal `%o`))

@taocp's answer explains why you can use both `%f` and `%lf` with `printf`, but note you can't do it with `scanf`

Comment: That makes sense.  But is there a reason why `%lf` was chosen?  It's obviously not a random couple of letters, 'so it does stand for `Long Float`, right?  Again, I know `Long Float` is not a type.

Comment: @Nealon There are quite a few input/display formats that need to be encoded with only 26 letters, so `%lf` was chosen to specify reading a `double` in `scanf()`, because `f` already meant `float` and `l` was already an optional letter to indicate “larger”. Think about it as “long float” if you want but do not call it that in public if you do not want to make people laugh.

Comment: @PascalCuoq so the `l` stands for larger?  Thats really all I needed to know.  I was simply told while learning c++ that the `l` stood for long.

Comment: @Nealon `l` is one of the “length” characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders . Note that this page is for printing. The format coincide with the formats for scanning where it makes sense, but as you already know, there are subtle variations, including that `%f` is usually used for printing a `double`.

Answer (score 5):

The `long float` is a K&R C first edition type that existed. It is synonymous with `double`.

After the first standard C89/C90, `long float` is removed. It is not deprecated. C89/C90 is also K&R C second edition. Then there is the multilingual amendment known as C94/C95 that adds `wchar_t`, as well as features such as `<iso646.h>`.

Many features of K&R C first edition are deprecated but not removed until the second standard C99. Automatic return type to int is removed, and default parameter type to int and double is removed from C99. The C99 standard requires function prototype, not function declaration i.e. `int function_declaration();` vs `int function_prototype(void);`. It also removed the K&R C style prototype.

```
// implicit int type
main(argc, argv)
char ** argv;

// explicit int type
int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char ** argv;
```

C++ started long before C was standardized. Templates were standardized in 1983, making it harder to compile to C code. It was not standardized until 1998. Old compilers may have deprecated old features that are removed with more contemporary compilers. The `%lf` is a legacy of `long float` that gets carried forward for C's standard library.

Answer (score 0):

For `scanf` you pass a pointer to the location where the result will be stored; you read a `float` value with `%f` and a double value with `%lf`; you have to distinguish them because `float` and `double` are not required to have the same representation. For `printf` you pass in the value to be displayed, and `float` values get promoted to `double` because they're passes as arguments in the `...` portion of the prototype; that is, for `printf` there's no difference between a `float` and a `double`, so `%f` and `%lf` do the same thing.