# Scanf/Printf double variable C

Tags: c, double, printf, stdout, stdin

Let's say I have this following bit of code in C:

```
double var;
scanf("%lf", &var);
printf("%lf", var);
printf("%f", var);
```

It reads from stdin variable 'var' and then prints twice in stdout 'var'.
I understand that's how you read a double variable from stdin, but my questions are:

1. Why can you print a double with %lf?
2. Why can you print a double with %f?
3. Which one is better and correct to use?

Comment: In `printf` they are the same.

Comment: `scanf` takes pointers, which can't be promoted, but `printf` takes values which can. in terms of printing, I'd probably use `%lf` as it's clearer to anyone reading your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For variable argument functions like `printf` and `scanf`, the arguments are promoted, for example, any smaller integer types are promoted to `int`, `float` is promoted to `double`.

`scanf` takes parameters of pointers, so the promotion rule takes no effect. It must use `%f` for `float*` and `%lf` for `double*`.

`printf` will never see a `float` argument, `float` is always promoted to `double`. The format specifier is `%f`. But C99 also says `%lf` is the same as `%f` in `printf`:

> C99 §7.19.6.1 The `fprintf` function
>
> `l` (ell) Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long int` or `unsigned long int` argument; that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long int` argument; that a following `c` conversion specifier applies to a `wint_t` argument; that a following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `wchar_t` argument; or **has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.**

Answer (score 13):

When a `float` is passed to `printf`, it is automatically converted to a `double`. This is part of the *default argument promotions*, which apply to functions that have a variable parameter list (containing `...`), largely for historical reasons. Therefore, the “natural” specifier for a `float`, `%f`, must work with a `double` argument. So the `%f` and `%lf` specifiers for `printf` are the same; they both take a `double` value.

When `scanf` is called, pointers are passed, not direct values. A pointer to `float` is not converted to a pointer to `double` (this could not work since the pointed-to object cannot change when you change the pointer type). So, for `scanf`, the argument for `%f` must be a pointer to `float`, and the argument for `%lf` must be a pointer to `double`.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I read manual pages, scanf says that 'l' length modifier indicates (in case of floating points) that the argument is of type double rather than of type float, so you can have 'lf, le, lg'.

As for printing, officially, the manual says that 'l' applies only to integer types.  So it might be not supported on some systems or by some standards.  For instance, I get the following error message when compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

```
a.c:6:1: warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘%lf’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
```

So you may want to doublecheck if your standard supports the syntax.

To conclude, I would say that you read with '%lf' and you print with '%f'.

Comment: If one uses the C99 and C11 spec as "officially", they say "l ... has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier.".

Comment: What is “the manual“? This is not a useful reference without a title and version. Additionally, the current year is 2013, so using software specifications from 1990 when more modern versions are available should be discouraged.