# Printing Double data type in C

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tfmw.jpg)Why in ***C***, when I print a **double type variable** with %lf it shows 0.000000…but if I use just **%f** it shows the desire result? Moreover, when we take an input we use %lf for double type variable. 
Why i am getting **0.0000** instead of ***3.0000*** ?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: This is probably already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952200/scanf-printf-double-variable-c

Comment: The answer of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952200/scanf-printf-double-variable-c
is not able to give a perfect definition of my shared picture.
Why it is giving 0.0000 instead of 3.0000

Comment: Hi, if you look at Artem Shinkarov's answer in the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952200/scanf-printf-double-variable-c, you will get your answer...

Comment: I ran your code on codechef online compiler and it gave me the desired answer : 3.000000, so, it maybe so, that your compiler doesn't allow "lf"...

Comment: try running your same code in this ide : https://www.codechef.com/ide

Answer (score 2):

```
for printf %f and %lf can be used interchangeably for floats and double.
for scanf %f  formats float
for scanf %lf formats double
```

Reason is that scanf take pointer(address of variable) as the input in both cases. Whereas in case of printf which takes actual variables (float or double) as the input parameters which are convertible to each other(type casting)