# Display double variable with scanf and without scanf

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf

I have an issue about display the value of a variable with double date type.

I already had looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f), [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952200/scanf-printf-double-variable-c), [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672829/printing-double-data-type-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c?rq=2). However it did not help me.

Below is the issue:
Here is the **code with scanf command. **

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
double a, b, c , x0, Delta; 
printf("Inter three numbers:");
scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c);  
Delta = b*b - 4*a*c;  
printf("The value of Delta is %f \n", Delta);
x0 = -b/(2.0*a); 
printf("\n the value of x0= %f", x0); 
return 0; 
}
```

**With scanf command**
I type 1 2 1, then $x0=0.000000$. It is the wrong result.

**Without scanf command**
If I type $a=1,b=2,c=1$ directly, then I got x0 = 1.000000.

I want to use scanf command and obtain the correct result. It mean to obtain x0=1.000000 when a=1, b =2, c=1.

Comment: Try removing the commas from the `scanf()` format specifier. If you had checked the return code, you might have figured this out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scanf` format string has commas between the numbers, so that's how it's expecting the input to look.

If you enter `1 2 1`, the first `%lf` is matched by `1`, but then `2` doesn't match the comma, so it stops reading at that point, leaving `b` and `c` uninitialized.

You need to either enter the numbers with commas between them, or remove the commas from the format string.