# round() function produces a strange number

Tags: c++, c, printf

I declare double variables t and tau, and assign them values 1 and 0.00001
This line of code produces 536870912 in the console. What can be the reason?

`printf("%i\n",round(t/(tau*double(2))));`

By the way, I write code in a C++ compiler, but practically it's C.

Comment: Use `%lf` instead of `%i`

Comment: @Kalana this returns me "nan"

Comment: "*but practically it's C*" - No it isn´t. You use `double(2)`, which isn´t possible in C.

Comment: Code compiled with a C++ compiler is *by definition* C++ code. You *might* be able to compile it with a C compiler but also might not. Even if it compiles, the behavior might differ. As such, I'll remove the C tag, as you are using C++.

Comment: @Kalana This is *is* a C++ queston as the code above is shown to be C++, thus the C tag *is* wrong. Some people watch the C tag and are greatly annoted by C++ questions that are wrongly tagged. My edit was approved by others, please stop reverting these. Additionally, in C++ the header `stdio.h` is not necessarily available or has the intended behavior. One should use the `cstdio` and `cmath` headers instead. There are many minor differences with C and C++, eg. your main function does specify it doesn't take arguments in C++ -- but the same code doesn't do that in C. Stop mingling C and C++.

Comment: He trying to run `C` code. There for my answer was based on `C`. If he asked answer for `c++` my answer never be accepted. There for your edit suggestion on my answer was rejected by community not by me.

Comment: @Kalana No, `double(2)` is not C code, so he's obviously running C++. I've thus removed the C tag from the question but he's reverted the edit with no reasoning. Also, please tag me when answering, otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: @larkey his first and only tag was `C`. There for my answer was base on `C`. That was actually happened.

Comment: @Kalana if you compile code with a C++ compiler, it's C++.  And his code was evidently not C, despite his claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%lf` instead of `%i` and remove double line it is unnecessary because you are already defined variables as `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double t = 1, tau = 0.00001;

    printf("%lf\n", round(t/(tau*2)));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** -: `50000.000000`

---

If you want 50000 only you can edit your code into like this

```
double t = 1, tau = 0.00001;
int answer;

answer = round(t/(tau*2));
printf("%i\n", answer);
```

**Output** -: `50000`

Answer (score 3):

[`round`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/round.3.html) returns a `double`. Printing it with `%i` is undefined behaviour.

Use `%f` for printing `double`:

```
printf("%f\n",round(t/(tau*double(2))));
```

Comment: this returns me "nan" :(

Comment: `round` can return `NaN` too!

Comment: how should I modify this line so that it return ```50000``` ? Or it should as it is?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio `%f` can print double too. See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1

Comment: @NickTheDick I am not sure how you defined `t` and `tau`. See https://ideone.com/muZtuy which prints 5000.

Comment: @usr yes i realise now it's an issue with my code or compiler - ill try to look into it. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting. Your are right. Here is a according question just linked through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952200/scanf-printf-double-variable-c