# C Student Assignment, ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’

Tags: c, reference, double

I'm working on an assignment and I'm getting this warning:

```
C4_4_44.c:173:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat]
```

The variabled is declared in main as:

```
double carpetCost;
```

I'm calling the function as:

```
getData(&length, &width, &discount, &carpetCost);
```

And here's the function:

```
void getData(int *length, int *width, int *discount, double *carpetCost)

{

    // get length and width of room, discount % and carpetCost as input

    printf("Length of room (feet)? ");

    scanf("%d", length);

    printf("Width of room (feet)? ");

    scanf("%d", width);

    printf("Customer discount (percent)? ");

    scanf("%d", discount);

    printf("Cost per square foot (xxx.xx)? ");

    scanf("%f", carpetCost);

    return;

} // end getData
```

This is driving me crazy because the book says that you don't use the & in

```
scanf("%f", carpetCost);
```

when accessing it from a function where you passed it be reference.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You might want to read a [`scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: This is intended for inconsistency with printf, in order that it's not easy to remember: `printf("%f", double_value)`; `scanf("%f", &float_value)`.

Comment: @vaxquis just saw this after asking my question a long time ago and wanted to explain. I was taking a class, doing searches, and was frustrated because I did not know the correct search terms to use, so I was turning up nothing. Sorry if I gave the impression that I was trying to use the forum to do my homework for me. I'm actually an adult in his 50s who is a firm believer in doing his own work. Peace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%f", carpetCost);
```

with

```
scanf("%lf", carpetCost);
```

`%f` conversion specification is used for a `float *` argument, you need `%lf` for `double *` argument.

Comment: Thanks! I just saw your response at the same time I figured it out! Man, you guys are FAST!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Use `%lf` specification instead for `double *` argument.

```
scanf("%lf", carpetCost);
```

Comment: I just figured it out, then looked and saw your answer. Boy, do I feel silly! :-)

Many thanks for a super quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Use `%lf` instead of `%f` if you are scanning a double type of variable. You can check this in detail also about `%lf` & `%f` from the discussed thread's link.

[Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)