# C programming calculate rectangle's area

Tags: c, area

I am writing a program to calculate a rectangle's area.

Eg.

> Enter top left point: 1 1 (User input)
>   Enter bottom right point: 2 -1 (User input)
>   Top Left x = 1.000000 y: 1.000000 
>   Bottom Right x = 2.000000 y: -1.000000 
>   Area = 2.000000 (Program output)

But mine is:

> Enter top left point: 1 1 (User input)
>   Enter bottom right point: 2 -1 (User input)
>   w: 1.000000
>   h: 2.000000
>   w*h: 2.000000
>   Rectangle Area: 1.000000 // **This is the problem, it should be printed out as *2.000000* instead.**

.

```
typedef struct { 
    double x; 
    double y; 
} Point; 


typedef struct { 
    Point topLeft; /* top left point of rectangle */
    Point botRight; /* bottom right point of rectangle */
} Rectangle; 


Point p;
Rectangle r;


printf("Enter top left point : ");
scanf("%lf",&r.topLeft.x);
scanf("%lf",&r.topLeft.y);
fflush(stdin); 
printf("Enter bottom right point : ");
scanf("%lf",&r.botRight.x);
scanf("%lf",&r.botRight.y);
computeArea(&r);
printf("Rectangle Area : %lf",r);



double computeArea(Rectangle *r)
{ 
    double h=0,w=0,z=0;
    w=fabs(r->topLeft.x - r->botRight.x);
    printf("w : %lf\n",w);
    h=fabs(r->botRight.y - r->topLeft.y);
    printf("h : %lf\n",h);
    z=w*h;
    printf("w*h : %lf\n",z);
    return (z);
}
```

Comment: Your program is just doing what you told it to do. Check the value you are printing in main().

Answer (score 2):

you cannot print a Rectangle

```
Rectangle r;
// ...
printf("Rectangle Area : %lf",r); // <== you cannot print a Rectangle with printf
```

Turn on your compiler warnings

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
computeArea(&r);
printf("Rectangle Area : %lf",r);
```

to:

```
printf("Rectangle Area : %lf", computeArea(&r));
```

As others have already noted, yiu need to add a prototype for `computeArea` before `main` (or move the whole function above `main`), and you should enable compiler warnings, then understand and fix all resulting warnings.

Also note that you should not use `fflush(stdin)` - never call `fflush` on an input stream - it results in undefined behaviour on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has actually *explained* the issue itself, problem is line `computeArea(&r);`

That function gives result as return value, which you then ignore completely. You can store it in a variable like this:

```
double area = computeArea(&r);
```

Then you can print the double value like this:

```
printf("Rectangle Area : %f", area);
```

You could also just call the function in the argument list without adding a variable, like shown in another answer. Point is, you need to catch the return value.

Note: use just `%f` with both double and float (which is automatically coerced to double when using `printf` or other variable argument function). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f) for more about that.