# C++ scanf %la returns 0

Tags: c++, cygwin, scanf

```
Win7 64-bit
gcc 4.8.2
g++ -Wall
```

I tried to format my C++ sscanf as defined in [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f/210595#210595) but the return is x == 0. The program is given below. I can't figure out what I did wrong so any advice is welcome.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <ios>
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char buffer[30];
   double x = 5.0;
   sprintf(buffer, "%a", 1.2);
   sscanf(buffer, "%la", &x);
   cout << "    Example 1.2 buffer -> " << buffer << endl;
   cout << "    Example 1.2 scanf <- " << x << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

output

```
 Example 1.2 buffer -> 0x1.3333333333333p+0
 Example 1.2 scanf <- 0
```

Comment: Works when I try it on gcc 4.7.2 on Linux, and with clang on OS X. Presume you're aware that `%a` is not standard? The man page does suggest that `l` should not be used with `%a`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: `%a` can be found in the C 2011 standard. Section 7.21.6.1, Paragraph 8.

Comment: @sharth: This is a C++ program, though.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: __C++ 2011 17.6.1.2 Paragraph 4:__ Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header `cname` shall be the same as that of the corresponding header `name.h`, as specified in the C standard library or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion.

Comment: @sharth: I'm not sure whether `%a` came in the C11 or C99, the latter (along the the TRs) being the one incorporated into C++, but you may be right. Either way, not sure about gcc 4.8.2., but gcc 4.7.2 warns about it, even with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: `sscanf` returns a result indicating how many items were successfully scanned. What value does your `sscanf` call return? (It returns 1 for me.)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: `"%a"` was introduced by C99. What man page suggests not using `l` with `%a`? `"%la"` is correct.

Comment: gcc doesn't implement `sscanf`; the runtime library does. If you're using a gcc installation uses the Microsoft library, it might not fully implement `sscanf`; Microsoft tends not to support C99 and later very well.

Comment: @KeithThompson: `man scanf(3)` in the Linux Programmer's Manual. It doesn't come out and say don't do it, but `a` is not one of the listed conversions for `l`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I think that's just an accidental omission. It says farther down that `a` is equivalent to `f`, so `"%la"` should be (and is) equivalent to `"%lf"`. (`"%a"` doesn't require hexadecimal for input.)

Comment: Code could check the result of `sscanf(buffer, "%la", &x);` as in `if (sscanf(buffer, "%la", &x) != 1) HandleError();`.   Pedantic code would do `int n; if (sscanf(buffer, "%la%n", &x, &n) != 1 || buffer[n]) HandleError();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE: There's a bug in the Cygwin runtime library "newlib" dealing with hexadecimal floating-point input. As of April 2021, a fix has been submitted but not yet released.]

I see nothing wrong with your code.  When I compile and run it on my Linux system, the output is:

```
    Example 1.2 buffer -> 0x1.3333333333333p+0
    Example 1.2 scanf <- 1.2
```

The `%a` specifier for the `*printf` and `*scanf` functions was introduced in C99, and incorporated into C++11. For the `sprintf` call, `"%a"` is a valid format for an argument of type `double`, and for the `sscanf` call `"%la"` is a valid format for an argument of type `double*`.

The version of gcc (or g++) is not directly relevant to the problem. gcc is just the compiler; the `sscanf` function is implemented by the runtime library.

When I compile and run your program under Cygwin on Windows 7, I get the same incorrect output you do. Cygwin uses the "newlib" C library, which differs from the glibc library used on most Linux systems.

If you're using a MinGW installation of gcc, if I recall correctly it uses the Microsoft C library. Microsoft's support for C standards later than 1990 is not good, so it's not too surprising if it doesn't implement `sscanf`'s `"%la"` format correctly.

Note that you don't need to use `"%la"` for hexadecimal input. For the `*scanf` functions, the `a`, `e`, `f`, and `g` specifiers are all equivalent, and will accept either decimal or hexadecimal floating-point input. So you should be able to use:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &x);
```

But if `"%la"` doesn't work, chances are `"%lf"` won't work either.

The `sscanf` function returns an `int` result indicating how many items were successfully scanned. You should always check that result. (Though if my experiment on Cygwin is any guide, it won't do any good in this case; `sscanf` returned `1` but still set `x` to `0.0`.)

Bottom line: Your code is ok, but you're probably using a runtime library that doesn't support what you're trying to do.

Here's another program (it's straight C but it should work as C++) that should give a bit more information. `sprintf` returns the number of characters written; `sscanf` returns the number of items read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[40];
    char leftover[40];
    double x = 5.0;
    int sprintf_result = sprintf(buffer, "%a", 1.2);
    printf("sprintf returned %d, buffer = \"%s\"\n", sprintf_result, buffer);
    int sscanf_result = sscanf(buffer, "%lf%s", &x, leftover);
    printf("sscanf returned %d, x = %f", sscanf_result, x);
    if (sscanf_result >= 2) {
        printf(", leftover = \"%s\"", leftover);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

On my Linux system, I get the correct output, which is:

```
sprintf returned 20, buffer = "0x1.3333333333333p+0"
sscanf returned 1, x = 1.200000
```

Under Cygwin, I get this output:

```
sprintf returned 20, buffer = "0x1.3333333333333p+0"
sscanf returned 2, x = 0.000000, leftover = "x1.3333333333333p+0"
```

which indicates that the `"%lf"` format caused `sscanf` to consume just the `0`, leaving the rest of the string to be consumed by the `"%s"`. This is characteristic of a C90 implementation (before `"%a"` was added to the standard) -- but `printf`'s `"%a"` works correctly.

Try this on your system.

UPDATE 7 years later: I still see the same problem with Cygwin under Windows 10. Further experimentation shows that it doesn't support *either* the `%a` format specifier *or* hexadecimal floating-point input. In C99 and later, then `a`, `e`, `f`, and `g` specifiers all behave the same way, accepting decimal or hexadecimal input, so for example, a `%la` format should accept input like `1.0`. I've submitted a bug report to the Cygwin mailing list: https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2021-April/248315.html

UPDATE 2: A patch has been pushed to newlib-cygwin that should fix this, and new developer snapshots are available. If all goes well, I presume Cygwin will be updated with this fix Real Soon Now.

https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2021-April/248323.html

Comment: )(*)(*&13146)(*^) darn. I use gcc on cygwin. I would like to stay with this and not go to mingw unless I have to (and you mentioned the incompatibility issues w/MSVC libraries). Is there any other choice than to bypass the issue?

Comment: Same here. April 21 2021: confirm that the problem with Cygwin under Windows 10 exists: my test _shows that it doesn't support either the %a format specifier or hexadecimal floating-point input_.

Comment: BTW, in C it is called `hexadecimal-floating-constant`, in C++ it is called `hexadecimal-floating-literal`. Why there is no consistency in terminology? Confused.

Comment: @pmor Discussion on the mailing list (see the link at the bottom of this answer) indicates that there's already a patch to fix this: https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2021-April/248323.html and a snapshot that you can try. I expect this will be in a Cygwin update Real Soon Now (though of course I can't guarantee anything).

Comment: @pmor I'm not sure, but I suspect that Bjarne Stroustrup just liked the word "literal" better than "constant". The terminology changed from to *floating-constant* to *floating-literal* between the 2nd (1991) and 3rd (1997) editions of Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" book. (I find "literal" clearer myself, since it avoids confusion with "constant expression" and "const", but the inconsistency is unfortunate.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Another example: C: _integer constant expression_, C++: _integral constant expression_.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(buffer, "%a", 1.2);
```

> Example 1.2 buffer -> 0x1.3333333333333p+0

The %a format reads the number into hexadecimal floating point format. The number in this format is represented in the form

0xB.CpN

where

- 0x, prefix
- B, one hexadecimal digit that represents the leading 1 bit of a normalized binary fraction
- C, hex digit fractional part
- N, 2 to the power of N

so:

0x1.3333333333333p+0

is a representation of

1.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011 x 2^0

This hexadecimal format represents the double-precision floating-point number nearest to the decimal number 1.2.

Regarding why in your example

> Example 1.2 scanf <- 0

Compiled with gcc 4.7.2 this works correctly as well as with [4.8.1](http://ideone.com/JsFs5W). The problem is in run-time library you link against.

Comment: ITYM 1.2 at the end, not 1.3

Comment: The question is why the `sscanf` call sets `x` to zero. How does this answer that question?

Comment: Downvoting because you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson corrected, there is an answer to both questions now

Comment: Both question? I only saw one (implied) question, and your answer "The problem is in run-time library you link against." doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: @KeithThompson well I think it is enough informative to know what to do (and your own answer elaborates what libraries are available, but this is just its information amount under compression)