# Input hexadecimal floating point number using scanf() and conversion specifier "%a"

Tags: c

I'm testing conversion specifiers both for `printf()` and `scanf()` function. I hadn't problem with `%a` format specifier for floating point hexadecimal number used in `printf()` function. It displayed what I expected. But I encountered problem when I wanted to input hexadecimal float using

```
scanf("%a", &var);
```

I'm using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float var;

    printf("Enter variable:\n");
    scanf("%a", &var);
    printf("var = %f\n", var);
    printf("var = %e\n", var);
    printf("var = %a\n", var);

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter a sample value, e.g. 0x1.205b0cp-11 that is 5.5e-4 it gives me that result:

`Enter variable: 0x1.205bc0p-11`

`var = 0.000000 var = 0.000000e+000 var = 0x0.000000p+0`

Whatever number I enter it always gives me 0. What's the reason or solution for that problem. I have no idea what I'm making wrong.

Comment: It works for me. Always check the value returned by `scanf`; it tells you how many items it successfully read.

Comment: Works for me on my machine, too.

Comment: Might be worth testing with `scanf("%f", &var);` to see if that works, to see if maybe the problem is that your system's `scanf` doesn't properly support `%a`.   What is your system and compiler, anyway?

Comment: @Steve Summit I'm using `gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0` running on `Windows 10 Version 21H2`. According to what you pointed, `scanf("%f", &var)` gives me proper result if I input decimal floating point.

Comment: @KarolChojecki Under Windows, I believe that gcc/mingw use some of the Microsoft C libraries, and those libraries are known to have some significant deficiencies.  I hadn't heard of total failure to parse `%a`, but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: The input to `%a` is supposed to begin with `0x`, but it might be worth trying just `1.205b0cp-11` instead.  (Although, when I tried that, I got `1.205` instead of `5.5e-4`.)

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900921) and [Keith Thompson's answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900921#23901476).

Answer (score 1):

That code works on my system<sup>(a)</sup>, producing the expected result:

```bash
pax> ./prog
Enter variable: 0x1.205bc0p-11
var = 0.000550
var = 5.500000e-04
var = 0x1.205bcp-11
```

Keep in mind that hexadecimal floating point constants (and the `%a` conversion specifier) were introduced in C99, so you should make sure you're using a compiler that handles that. Most modern ones will, but some people may be locked in to a certain level if the vendor isn't keen on keeping up to date<sup>(b)</sup>.

Keep in mind that the `scanf` family, conversion specifiers `a`, `e`, `g`, and `f` (and their upper-case variants) are all the same - they each handle *every* format that `strtod` handles. The (likely) reason that they all exist is to mirror the `printf` conversion specifiers where it makes a difference to how the value is output.

It's possibly worth testing with a variety of inputs *less* advanced than hex floating point, and work your way up to there. For example, the sequence `{ 0, 3, 3.1, 3.14159. 9e2, 6e-2, ... }`. That would at least let you know *where* the input is failing.

Also, it's a good idea to test the conversion to ensure it works (this is true of all calls where failure can adversely affect future program behaviour). In other words, something like this in place of your `scanf` statement:

```c
if (scanf("%a", &var) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went horribly wrong!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup>  My system, by the way, is `gcc 9.4.0` (from `gcc --version`) running on `Ubuntu 20.04.2` (from `cat /etc/lsb_release`). It's often a good idea to include that sort of information in questions, it can help us figure out issues more quickly.

<sup>(b)</sup> Possibly a good reason to consider changing vendors though, of course, subject to normal cost/benefit analysis.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. I'm using `gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0` running on `Windows 10 Version 21H2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try **computing** somehow like with `printf("var = %e\n", var/7.0 + var *var);`.  Sometimes simple code without doing any math does not link in the math library needed by `printf()`.