# C Read file doubles with leading spaces

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file with a header of two lines, and the rest contains two columns of double data like

```
    0.0030556304       -0.0078125
```

The first column is 16 characters long, and the second column is 17 characters long, after there is a space and the '\n'.

My code to read this file is

```
nscan = fscanf(sound_file, "%lf %lf %c", &value1,
                                          &value2,
                                          &termch);
```

I use `termch` to test further for newline character.

I've tried with

```
nscan = fscanf(sound_file, "%16lf %16lf %c", &value1,
                                          &value2,
                                          &termch);
```

too.

But when I printf the with

```
printf("%f %f\n", value1, value2);
```

the result is

-0.000000 -0.000000

Am I missing something?

Comment: _file with a header of two lines_ skip two lines?

Comment: Use `%lf` to print doubles

Comment: What is the value of `nscan` after you scanf?

Comment: @CoolGuy: that is not useful: `printf("%f")` is exactly the same as `printf("%lf")`.  The documentation says so.

Comment: @JohnZwinck ,So the difference comes when using it in `scanf`?

Comment: Thanks to all guys, I finally discovered that I already has read the file until the end. So I made **rewind** to put pointer in beginning of the file. Now it's works.

Comment: @CoolGuy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f

Comment: fscanf is fine, however, %lf format specifier for double variable and %f for float, be consistent in that

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf(sound_file, "%lf %lf %c"...` is not doing what you think.

The space before `"%c"` consumes all white-space including `' '` and `'\n'`.  The following `"%c"` will consume the next `char` (which must be non-white-space at this point), if any.

---

Better to read all files lines using `fgets()` and then scan the buffer with `sscanf()`

```
char buf[100];


// Read 2 header lines and toss
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, sound_file) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, sound_file) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();

// Insure code is using a type the match format specifiers
// Could be a problem in OP's unposted code.
double value1, value2;

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, sound_file) != NULL) [
  int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%lf%lf", &value1, &value2);
  if (cnt != 2) Handle_MissingData();
  else Use(value1, value2);
}
```

---

`fscanf("%lf",...` scans for optional leading white-space and then for a double.  A leading `" "` before the `"%lf"` is not needed.

`fscanf("%16lf",...` will *limit* the total number of non-white-space `char` scanned to 16.