# minus function acting crazy

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

Just a program here that subtracts a number from another number. I'm getting differences of -23882489428948248829...etc...can you tell why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double minus(double a, double b) { // set up minus function
    double difference = a - b;
    return difference;
}

int main() //begin program
{
    double a; //declare variables in this scope 
    double b;

    printf("Enter the first number:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &a); //get a from user

    printf("Enter the second number:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &b); //get b from user

    printf("The difference is %f\n", minus(a,b)); //print results
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `"%lf"` for `double` in `scanf`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But I remember old days of Turbo C, `%f` was ok for both float and double? But in Visual Studio it behaves strange.

Comment: Why people downvote without comment?

Comment: You will get your exact answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/210590/744616

Comment: the printf format "%f" is not correct for a double value,  rather use "%lf"

Comment: @user3629249 `%f` and `%lf` of `printf` are both valid.

Comment: regarding function scanf() 1) the returned value from scanf() should always be checked to assure the operation/conversion was successful. 2) the format string needs to skip over any 'left over' white space in the input stream.  Therefore, the format string should be: " %lf" <-- notice the leading ' ' (space)

Comment: @PranitKothari I do not know how was the Turbo C. But `%lf` of scanf is already enabled on the C89.

Comment: @user3629249 most scanf specifiers, including `%lf`, already skip leading whitespace. your suggested space is redundant

Comment: @PranitKothari: For `printf`, `float` arguments are promoted to `double`, so `%f` is valid for both. For `scanf`, the argument is a pointer, and there is no promotion, so two different format strings are needed: `%f` for `float*`, `%lf` for `double*`. I'm skeptical that this was any different under Turbo C (unless `float` and `double` had the same size and representation, but that seems unlikely).

Comment: @PranitKothari: In days of Turbo C, `"%f"` was ok for both float and double for `printf()`.  Code needed `"%lf"` for `double` (actually `double*`) and `"%f"` for `float`  for `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

For `double a` `%lf` should be used instead of `%f` because in scanf_s/scanf when you pass double with %f, it will be indicated for 4 byte entity, and double is of 8 bytes (in Visual Studio).

Sizes may differ on compiler implementation, but mostly above mentioned reason stay relevant.

Comment: The sizes don't have to be 4 and 8

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know int differs in size as per OS, but double and float too?

Comment: all types may have any size (with character types being `1`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have updated my answer, but that was really new for me. I always assumed double/float are of fixed size.

Comment: With `scanf()`, `"%lf"` is used with `double *` and `"%f"` is used with `float *`.  Both are pointers.  On every machine I've used, these pointers are the same size, but by spec they _could_ differ.