# Why Conversion Specification %lf does not work for Double in printf

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I am writing a very small code just `scanf` and `printf`. I am reading a double value and printing it. The conversion specification `%lf` works properly to read a double value. But, it doesn't work with printf.

When I am trying to print that value I am getting output like `0.000000`

```
double fag;
scanf("%lf", &fag);
printf("%lf", fag);
```

But, if I use %f in printf it works properly.

Comment: [It is working !](http://ideone.com/kD048E)

Comment: What compiler / C library are you using?

Comment: [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210590/995714)

Answer (score 6):

The C standard library implementation you're using doesn't conform to C99 (or newer). The changes listed in the foreword (paragraph 5) contain:

> `%lf` conversion specifier allowed in `printf`

The description of the `l` length modifier is (**C99+TC3 7.19.6.1 par. 7**, emphasis mine):

> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long int` or `unsigned long int` argument; that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long int argument`; that a following `c` conversion specifier applies to a `wint_t` argument; that a following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `wchar_t` argument; **or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.**

`%f` and `%lf` are therefore equivalent. Both expect a `double` because arguments matching the ellipsis (the `...` in `int printf(char const * restrict, ...);`) undergo the so-called default argument promotions. Among other things they implicitly convert `float` to `double`. It doesn't matter for `scanf()` since pointers aren't implicitly converted.

So if you can't or don't want to update to a newer C standard library `%f` can always be used in a `printf()` format string to print `float` or `double`. However in `scanf()` format strings `%f` expects `float*` and `%lf` expects `double*`.