# `l` length modifier has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, c99, format-specifiers

I am trying to understand the following [section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html):

> `l (ell)`
>
> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion
>   specifier applies to a `long` or `unsigned long` argument; that a
>   following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long`
>   argument; that a following `c` conversion specifier applies to a `wint_t`
>   argument; that a following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer
>   to a `wchar_t` argument; or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`,
>   `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.

I can also see that this is consistent with [cppreference:fprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) where `"%f"` and `"%lf"` are equivalent for `printf()` family.

So is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222471/136285) erroneous ? Or does `C99` makes it clear now that `"%f"` is for `float`, while `"%lf"` is for `double` for `printf()` family functions ?

Comment: If you continue to read the linked answer you will see *why* both the `printf` formats are for `double`. It has to do with how arguments are passed to variable argument functions by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - The answer that you linked is perfectly fine. `%f` in `printf()` can handle `double` and `float`, both type of argument.

---

**Information:** `printf()` is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

As per `C99`, chapter 7.19.6.3

#### Syntax

> `#include <stdio.h>`
>   `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`

and regarding the `%f` format specifier,

> `f,F`
>
> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted to
>   decimal notation in the style *[−]ddd.ddd*, where the number of digits after
>   the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. [....]

So, we see, the standard *only* mentions `double`. Curious about its *younger counterpart*, `float`?

Then, from chapter §6.5.2.2, paragraph 7

> [...] The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

and, regarding the *default argument promotions* part, (*emphasis mine*), paragraph 6,

> [...] If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, **and arguments that
>   have type `float` are promoted to `double`**. These are called the default argument
>   promotions. [...]

so, for `printf()` function, with `%f` format specifier, it does not matter whether the supplied argument is of type `float` or `double`, it will get promoted to `double` anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation is correct: `printf` sees no difference between `float` and `double`.

Parameters of functions from the `printf` family are taken through the variable-length mechanism. In the variable-length part of a variable-length argument list, the "default argument promotions" apply: types `char` and `short int` are promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`.