# scanf behavior of passing address of a pointer(address variable)

Tags: c, scanf

I know this is the incorrect way to use scanf( ). But I want an expert in C to answer this question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *a;
    printf("please input one number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("your input is %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
please input one number:
30
your input is 30
```

since *a already exist, it won't bring ***segment fault*** while executing.
and scanf( ) magically fill correct data into *a, made (int *) into (int); then printf( ) will output correctly.

I think this code could work because of sizeof(int*) and sizeof(int) is the same value on my system. So I also do check some type size on my system:

```
sizeof(short) return 2
sizeof(short*) return 4
sizeof(int) return 4
sizeof(int*) return 4
sizeof(long) return 4
sizeof(long*) return 4
sizeof(float) return 4
sizeof(float*) return 4
sizeof(double) return 8
sizeof(double*) return 4
sizeof(char) return 1
sizeof(char*) return 4
```

seems this code could also work when float, but it doesn't. the code I try is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float *a;
    printf("please input one number:\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("your input is %f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
please input one number:
3.5
your input is -0.034267
```

scanf( ) should work since I use %f when calling scanf( ). since I still give it a 4-bytes memory address.

I can't figure it out. could someone who is knowing the whole scanf( ) thing explain why these two codes(almost the same) works different way?

Comment: I think `float` is promoted to `double` when passed as one of variable length arguments.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be and what is the actual result? The address should be an integer number, therefore using %f to read it as float doesn't seem right.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* and it *happened* to work.

Comment: a is already an address -> `scanf("%d", a);` and `%d` should receive value `*a`, not address.

Comment: @AleksandarMakragić It is an usual way to use `scanf()` and `printf()`, but not for this experiment. Since `a` is not initialized, there will be big chance to get Segmentation Fault.

Comment: I know a is already an address, if I want scanf("%d", a), I'll call malloc() for it. but the scanf() seems only careing the address is initialized or not. if you do reserve enough memory for it, it should work anyway. isn't it?

Comment: Typically it might "work", but do not try to cause *undefined behavior* except for experiment!

Comment: `scanf()` treats parameters as being addresses of whatever type the format string specifies, regardless of what is actually passed.     `printf()`, similarly, treats parameters as being of whatever type is specified in the format string, regardless of what is actually passed - hence undefined behaviour if types don't match.   The only exception, for `printf()`, is that a `float` parameter is promoted to `double` before being passed so - when the format string specifies a `float` - `printf()` assumes a `double` was passed as the corresponding argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually data having type `float` is passed as variable length argument are promoted to `double` as @zch says, and `printf()` expects for it.

In this case, what is passed is `float*` and it won't become `double` magically.

That is why `printf()` get wrong data -- both data and size are wrong.

Comment: Right.  A four-byte `float *` gets passed, but `printf` tries to read an 8-byte double so that it can print it out as `%f`.

Comment: thanks, you're right. I search the entire forum gets this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f?rq=1