# Wrong Calculation ? C programming beginner

Tags: c

I'm learning c via a guide book and i am enjoying it.
However, there is one question that i am stuck.

The question is:

"Write a program that when writing number "x" and number "y", the program shows how much % of x is in y."

"The answer should be 64 % when x = 54 and y = 84"

Obviously, 54 / 84 = 0.64...  * 100, which is about 64 %.
However, when I run my program it shows 84.689699.
I tested without the "*100" but nothing. It shows 0.84689699...

Is my program wrong or is it a problem of the compiler or something?
I am a beginner and it would be very helpful if someone tells me what is wrong.

**PS: I use atom.io and gcc-compiler**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double vx;
  double vy;

  printf("Enter the 1st number : "); scanf("%f" , &vx);
  printf("Enter the 2nd number : "); scanf("%f" , &vy);

  printf("\a\n\nx is %f of y" , vx / vy * 100);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I also tried with 100.0 instead of 100 but nothing...

Comment: Read the warnings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f51b696c1f63219

Comment: %lf (lowercase L) not %f

Comment: @Pingu Please stop adding the C++ tag.  You say your are using C so there is no need for the C++ tag.  If you are actually using C++ then you should say so and remove the C tag.

Comment: See [why scanf needs %lf for doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

Comment: @tobi303 he is obviously using C and not C++ and should remove the C++ tag. To the question: Your compiler should give a warning that you use a wrong format specifier. Use `%lf` instead of `%f` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I know this is not c++ and undersdtand the difference between those 2 languages.

Comment: I didn't know the stackflow community was so huge. Answers came instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `scanf` is a variadic function the input can not be promoted.`scanf` takes a pointer as an input, therefore you need to specify it will `%lf`. If the input was a variable, not a pointer, C would promote float to double.  In your program `scanf` function has `%f` instead of `%lf`. Below code works fine and the output is `64.285714` on MinGW.

Also, refer to link [Correct format specifier for double in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)

```
int main(void)
{
  double vx;
  double vy;

  printf("Enter the 1st number : "); scanf("%lf" , &vx);
  printf("Enter the 2nd number : "); scanf("%lf" , &vy);

  printf("\a\n\nx is %f of y" , vx / vy * 100);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know the existence of %lf,

Comment: But there is a reason why you need `%lf` for `scanf`. You do not need it for `printf`. Read my answer.

Comment: Oh there is a page where they explain about  %lf but 5 pages after the question.... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your scanf function.

%f in a scanf function means your input will be put into a float variable.

use a %lf instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double vx;
  double vy;

  printf("Enter the 1st number : "); scanf("%lf" , &vx);
  printf("Enter the 2nd number : "); scanf("%lf" , &vy);

  printf("\a\n\nx is %f of y" , vx / vy * 100);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I dont know why they didnt mentionned about the %lf neither for the %f in the guide book.

Comment: @Pingu get a new book.

Comment: @Pingu or you can Google it.

Comment: @KevinKe yea but how to google if you dont know the existence of %lf ....