# scanf function not working

Tags: c, scanf

I've had this problem with a couple of programs now, and I can not figure out why this keeps happening. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

    double x = 0;

    while(x <= 0){
       printf("Enter a digit greater than 0.\n");
       scanf("%lf", &x);
    }

    printf("%lf", &x);
}
```

and the output is:

```
Enter a digit greater than 0.
4
0.000000
```

please help

Comment: Sure would help to check the return of `scanf` so you know if your input succeeded...

Comment: Note that "enter a digit" implies a single digit; you should refer to a number if you mean non-integral value or values from 10.00 upwards are allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

    double x = 0;

    while(x <= 0){
        printf("Enter a digit greater than 0.\n");
       scanf("%lf", &x);
    }

    printf("%lf", x);   
}
```

You are using

```
printf("%lf", &x);
```

But the correct syntax to print value of x is:

```
printf("%lf", x);
```

Check the working code https://ideone.com/lpdlmX

Answer (score 4):

First off,

```
printf ("%lf", &x);
```

will try to print the *address* of `x` rather than its value, and this is clearly into undefined behaviour territory<sup>(a)</sup>. A half-decent compiler should warn you about this such as, with `gcc`:

```
program.c: In function 'main':
program.c:13: warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type
    'double', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]
 printf ("%lf\n", &x);
         ^
```

---

Secondly, the normal `printf` specifier for double is `%f` rather than `%lf`. You can *use* the latter since the standard states it has no effect on certain data types but it's a bit of a waste doing so.

So what you need is actually:

```
printf ("%f", x);
```

The general rule is that you pass *addresses* to `scanf` because it needs to populate the objects at those addresses. For `printf`, you just pass the object *itself* (yes, even if the data is a pointer that you want printed *as* a pointer rather than pointing the object being pointed to).

---

And, finally, to make your code more robust, you would be wise to detect a problem with `scanf` since, it there's a problem with the input that leaves `x` set to zero, the program will *continuously* try to read that input, resulting in an infinite loop.

So a good starting point, taking all those comments into consideration, would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {
    double x = 0;

    while (x <= 0) {
        printf ("Enter a digit greater than 0.\n");
        if (scanf ("%lf", &x) != 1) {
            printf ("Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf ("%f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Specifically, from `ISO C11 7.21.6.1 /9`:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Always **always** check the return of `scanf`, that being said, you `printf ("%f", x);` -- there is no `&x` and no need for `%lf`, `printf` `%f` *format specifiers* prints doubles. (however it is required when using `scanf` -- `man scanf` and `man printf` are your friends)

Putting it altogether, you could safely take input as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    double x = 0;

    while(x <= 0){
        printf ("Enter a digit greater than 0.\n");
        if (scanf ("%lf", &x) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf ("%f", x);

}
```

**note:** you must exit the loop on conversion failure (or empty `stdin` before attempting to take input again -- or your input will fail) Reason: on a failed conversion - no additional characters are read leaving the characters causing the failure just waiting to bite you again on the next go-round...

Comment: if `x` is double then printf should have `%lf` should it not?

Comment: @tom Both  `"%lf"` and `"%f"` are valid for printing a `double` or `float` since C99.